Can I prepare saltwater far in-advance before water changes?
I was looking into maybe buying a five gallon water container and mixing all of my water in it. However, this would last me quite some time.
Is it healthy to have water sitting this long before usage? Or would stuff start to grow in it? Thank you so much for any help.
